# "Sliding" plane in a given curve

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Given a parametric curve $\mathbf{r}\left(s\right)$, where the parameter $s$ is the lenghth of the curve, lets define a plane $\Pi$ perpendicular to the curve at a specific $s=s_1$. Lets also define an arbitrary point $P \in \Pi$.

Now, lets "slide" the plane $\Pi$ along the curve to a new position $s=s_2$. My question is: How can I calculate the cordenates of the point $P$ in its new position as function of $s_1$, $s_2$, and $\mathbf{r}\left(s\right)$?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this a lesson on the Frenet-Serret formulas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plane $\Pi$ is spanned by normal and binormal vector fields so it's parametric equation is

$$v= \alpha(s) + \lambda N(s) + \mu B(s)$$.

If point $P$ at the beginning has coordinates $\alpha(s_1) + \lambda_0 N(s_1) + \mu_0 B(s_1)$ then in the end it will be $\alpha(s_2) + \lambda_0 N(s_2) + \mu_0 B(s_2)$.

Comment: Can this be extended to the case where the curve $\mathbf{r}$ is parameterized by using a generic parameter $\lambda$ (not necessary the length parameter $s$)? Thank you very much!

Comment: yes, you can calculate normal and binormal vector fields in terms of generic parameter: $B = \frac{\alpha'\times\alpha''}{\|\alpha'\times\alpha''\|}$ and $N = \frac{(\alpha'\times\alpha'')\times \alpha'}{\|\alpha'\times\alpha''\|\;\|\alpha'\\}$.